# can't initialize ifstream "Error reading characters of string"

Tags: c++, c++11, ifstream

the following gives me strange message:
The message appears inside ifstream text, (when hovering it)
path is a full windows style path, e.g.: "C:\t.txt"

```
void checkInput(string path)
{
ifstream text(path);
    // "...<Error reading characters of string.>..."
if (text.is_open())
{
    if (text.good())
               ...
```

the full message:

```
{_Filebuffer={_Set_eback=0xcccccccc <Error reading characters of string>.
_Set_egptr=0xcccccccc <Error reading characters of string>. ...} }
std::basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char>> "
```

I tried to use char* instead string, and string.c_str.
no good.

Thx for the answers,
it seems the code running even though I still get this message.
previously  I had another error in my code.

I thought of deleting this, but it might help to know that this message doesn't prevent the code from run.

Comment: show the call site, at least, and what is in "path"... Ah, and this seems to be a [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871996/error-opening-file-when-debugging)

Comment: It's likely a duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871996/error-opening-file-when-debugging). Are you incorrectly using relative paths? Also, include ALL the information needed to help you, is that "message" a compiler error? Is it printed at runtime? Did you use error-getting functions to obtain it?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you use path like you wrote "C:\t.txt" - it's incorrect. Use must use double backslash, like "c:\\t.txt"
2. If you use absolute path than check file exists with such a path.
3. If you use relative path, it depends on where you run your code: from VS (debug mode) or just run executable.

Comment: I've got the same issue as this poor guy. This information did not help. I have the correct absolute path with the correct \\ character and the file does in fact exist.

Comment: I have the same issue as well. Code works perfectly fine in a project by itself. Biggest mystery ever.